# Getting rss topics for arabic sites Dynamically

Tags: android, rss, rss-reader

I want to create an android App that getting Arabic news by RSS Feeds. 
I want to know if there are any way to dynamically get the Rss feeds and separate them according to its topics?

Thanks for Advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways of doing this.

The first way is to look for a source that provide you with different topics, here's an [example](http://techcrunch.com/rssfeeds/) of what I mean. With those different topics being treated as each individual news feed, you are able to display them separately.

The second way is to not directly display the feed using ListView. You should first, store the news feeds into somewhere for pre-processing, for instance, you can use SQLite. While storing each news, you include a new column for your desired 'grouping' for separation. After that, you can create an adapter that pull news from this source (or SQLite) and display them in your ListView.

*Pardon me for only providing you with the concepts, as I don't have a sample code to show you. I hope you understand what I am trying to describe to you.*